# Using kafka-handler 4.0 in HDP 3.1.4

Tags: hive, avro

We are using HDP 3.1.4 and want to use kafka-handler for Kafka and Hive integration.

Lots of our topics in Kafka are serialized with Avro using Confluent Schema Registry and the default kafka-handler shipped with HDP 3.1.4 does not contain new features for Avro messages  serialized with Confluent that contains *Magic Byte*. in new versions of kafka-handler we have some properties such as `'avro.serde.type'='skip'` and `'avro.serde.skip.bytes'='5'` to handle *Magic Byte*.

So we wanted to replace kafka-handler with our own compiled kafka-handler 4.0.
we simply started with  replacing kafka-handler 4.0 with default HDP kafka-handler but we faced this error :

```
MetaException(message:java.lang.NoSuchFieldError AVRO_SERDE_TYPE)
```

`AVRO_SERDE_TYPE` is added in `hive-serde 4.0` and we investigate it is because kafka-handler has dependency to `kafka-exec` and `kafka-exec` contains our old `hive-serde` that shipped with HDP.

We should replace `hive-serde` too. so we continue with shading `hive-serde` in kafka-handler:

```
<relocation>
  <pattern>org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2</pattern>
  <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2_shaded</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

but we face this exception:

```
SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling
statement: FAILED: ClassCastException class org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaSerDe
```

so how we should handle this issue ?